# C#: How to access array methods from parent object?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

My ctor return an object which is multidimentional array. Depends on constructor argument, the object returned by ctor can be different rank array, but always int.

```
object arr = new int[2,2,2];
```

or

```
object arr = new int[2,2,2,2,2];
```

or

```
object arr = new int[0,0];
```

Having `arr` object  constructed, and knowing what it is (`GetType()`), I'd like to access array methods like `Rank`, `GetLength`, `GetValue` etc. How I can access child specific methods from the `object` level? For now I have only  four methods for `arr` object accessible: `Equals`, `GetHashCode`, `GetType`, and `ToString`

Comment: Can I ask why you have it as a type `object` in the first place when you know its an integer array? (or similar at least)

Comment: You can type it as `Array` but still that's not a right thing to do. Type it as `int[]`. Your underlying problem is different. Maybe you need different implementation of the classes for different types of array.

Comment: @Sayse: yes I could store it as Array not as an object. Valid point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the object into an array, like this:

```
((int[])arr).Rank
((int[])arr).GetLength()
```

or

```
(arr as int[]).Rank
```

Comment: believe me or not, but I was just about to answer my question myself. My answer would be the same as yours. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could just declare your variable as `Array`:

```
Array arr = new int[2,2,2,2,2];
int rank = arr.Rank;
```

Or cast to Array:

```
object arr = new int[2,2,2,2,2];
Array array = (Array)arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast it back to an Array object and then these methods will be available!